# why my setstate not working after time end?

Tags: flutter

i'am complete beginner. I want a make some app. My first screen just image and after 5 seconds i want to go my login page. But my code not working.

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import "./loginmenu.dart";
import "./loginanimation.dart";

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void timer() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        loginmenu();
      });
      timer();
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: loginanimation());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `timer` function in `initState` method. I created small demonstration for you. After widget building for 5s the application is in animating state, if time expires we are in loaded state.

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 bool  _isAnimating = true;
  
 @override
 void initState() {
   timer();
  }
  
 Future<void> timer() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _isAnimating = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: _isAnimating ? Text('Animating') : Text('Loaded'));
  }
  
}
```

Comment: it is worked! thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

Better do:

```
const interval = Duration(seconds:5);

@override
initState() {
   Timer.periodic(interval, (Timer t) => setState((){}));
}
```

Comment: what the difference and why? if there is explanation must be very good

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` like this:

```
  Future<bool> myDelayedFuture() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
    return true;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: myDelayedFuture(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(
              child: Text('Welcome'),
            );
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```